# Points at infinity of a curve and prime divisors of it's function field.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I decided to read a little bit of algebraic function fields with finite fields of constants, and the Zeta function in prime characteristic. I haven´t look very deeply into the biblography I'm afraid, but for the moment I just wanted to clear a question I have. This is my first question here.

If $F$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{F}_p(x)$, then the places of $F$ are basically of two kinds: Prime ideals of the ring of elements of $F$ that are integral over $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$, and prime ideals of the ring of elements of $F$ that are integral over $\mathbb{F}_q[1/x]$, that contain $1/x$.

In a simple case, let's say $f(x,y)=0$ defines an affine variety $V$, and the function field of $V$, which we will write as $F$, is a finite extension of $\mathbb{F}_p(x)$.

I know that the affine points of $V$ are related to the places of the first kind of $F$, basically we have that
$$
\sum_{d|m} d\pi_d = N_m,
$$
where $N_m$ is the (usual) number of points of the variety $V$ (or actually $V(\overline{\mathbb{F}_p})$) in $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$, and $\pi_d$ is the number of divisors of the first kind that have degree $d$. This can be proven with the aid of Hilbert's Nullstellensatz.

**What I want to find is a (hopefully rather simple) way to prove that**
$$
\sum_{d|m} d\nu_d = P_m,
$$
where $\nu_d$ is the number of prime divisors of the second kind that have degree $d$, and $P_m$ are the number of points at infinity of the polynomial $f(x,y)$ in $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$ [that is the number of points of the form $(a,b,0) \in \mathbb{F}_{p^m}^{\times 3}$ such that $F(a,b,0)=0$ where $F$ is the homogenization of $f$].
I now I have placed this question on an elementary level, and surely a lot of people here know it to be true in the general case. **Here I ask where can I find a proof of this (in this basic example or in the general case) or if someone knows specific details that can help me in trying to figure out why this is true, or if actually the method for the proof of the first case applies to points at infinity as well** In the books I have came across I haven't read a detailed argument is provided for this, perhaps because they are advanced references. And I think it is true and makes sense, this is only an argument I want to see to complete the details of the usual proof that the Zeta function of an algebraic function field $F$ of a variety defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$
$$
Z(s) = \prod_{\mathfrak{p}} \frac{1}{1- |\mathfrak{p}|^{-s}}
$$
(product over all prime divisors of $F$), has the common representation (under a change of variables)
$$
Z(u)= \text{exp} \left(  \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{N_m u^m}{m} \right)
$$
where $N_m$ is the number of points of $V$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$ (both affine and at infinity).